# What is the Android 11 Easter Egg?

Tags: android-11, easter-egg

What is the Android 11 Easter Egg? If so how do you find it? Does Android 11 even have a Easter Egg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like with previous version, go to Settings -> About Phone -> Android Version. Tap on Android Version until the Easter egg appears.

Comment: Do you know what the easter egg is?

Comment: @Joshua by "easter egg", did you mean [the "Android Neko"](https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/theres-cute-cat-game-easter-egg-hidden-android-11s-smart-home-controls-0326882/)?

Comment: @AndrewT. Yes, Thank you.